# How to access Light Sensor data from React Native on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build an application that uses light sensor. However there is no npm package that enables me to access the light sensor on android on React Native 0.60+

So I can I write some android native code to access the sensor and pull it up to my React Native component ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?